# google sheets script run when rows are added and copy results to different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been running a script which splits comma separated data into new rows through a function on a different sheet from the source data. The amount of data has grown and the calculation is taking forever.

[taking forever progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqdih.png)

The example spreadsheet is here (with small amount of data):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e0YhJqHn62jju7KOOy5U2JZ5FLCv6_oeY-mc_jRF5-4/edit?usp=sharing

The script is the following:

```
function extract(range, colToSplit, delimiter) {
var resArr = [], row;
range.forEach(function (r) {
    r[colToSplit-1].replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(\d|\w)/g," , ").split(delimiter)
        .forEach(function (s) {
            row = [];
            r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
                row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
            })
            resArr.push(row);
        })
})
return resArr;}
```

The question is, how to run this script for new data only and copy the result into a different "static without-formulas" worksheet in a way where the script is not run with every change for ALL the data.

My highest regards to the script gods.

Comment: [A custom function must return a result in 30 seconds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) Personally, I would not run this as a cell function.  Clicking a button is not that big of a deal to me.

Comment: Hey Jairo, I have published a new solution. Let me know if it works for you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a cell function, you can use a script and trigger it through the editor or by using a button in your sheet. By doing so, you will benefit of their 6 minute time limit (see [the quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)).

The function can be modified as such, and then assign it to a button to be run as an onClick event (more about this [here](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/)):

```js
function extract() {
var resArr = [], row;
var colToSplit = 6;
var delimiter = " , ";
range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
range.forEach(function (r) {
    r[colToSplit-1].replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(\d|\w)/g," , ").split(delimiter)
        .forEach(function (s) {
            row = [];
            r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
                row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
            })
            resArr.push(row);
        })
})
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1].getRange(1, 1, resArr.length, resArr[0].length).setValues(resArr);
}
```

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create the html for your function in a sidebar very simply as follows:**

```
function showButtonDialog() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='<input type="text" id="rng" /> Range<br /><input type="text" id="col" /> Column<br /><input type="text" id="dlm" /> Delimiter<br /><input type="button" value="run extract" onClick="extract();" />';
  html+='<script>function extract() {google.script.run.extract(document.getElementById("rng").value,document.getElementById("col").value,document.getElementById("dlm").value);}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

This  will test that your getting the right parameters

```
function extract(a,b,c) {
  Logger.log('rng: %s col: %s del: %s',a,b,c);
}
```

You'll probably have to tweak your function a bit.  But from the looks of your code you'll have no trouble with that.

Comment: I've tried running the script with a manual button, however the process is even slower. I am considering a solution which only processes new entries and writes the results to a different sheet. Is this possible through a script?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that you unaccepted my previous answer; I assume that it does not serve your purpose anymore. Here I provide yet another solution doing what you originally asked - that is processing only the new rows. This is accomplished by use of [Script Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties).

See below all the code:

```js
var COL_TO_SPLIT = 6;
var DELIMITER = " , ";
var NUM_COLUMNS = 16;

function extract(range, colToSplit, delimiter) {
  var resArr = [];
  range.forEach(function (r) {
    r[colToSplit-1].replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(\d|\w)/g," , ").split(delimiter)
      .forEach(function (s) {
          var row = [];
          r.forEach(function (c, k) {               
              row.push( (k === colToSplit-1) ? s.trim() : c);
          });
          resArr.push(row);
      });
  });
  return resArr;
}

function getCurrentRow() {
  var currentRow = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('currentRow');
  if (currentRow === null) {
    currentRow = 2;
  }
  return parseInt(currentRow);
}

function updateCurrentRow(newRow) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('currentRow', newRow);
}

// Returns the new "currentRow"
function migrateRowsFrom(row) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var rowsToProcess = sourceSheet.getLastRow() - row + 1;
  if (rowsToProcess <= 0) return sourceSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var rows = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, rowsToProcess, NUM_COLUMNS).getDisplayValues();

  var extracted = extract(rows, COL_TO_SPLIT, DELIMITER);
  destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, extracted.length, extracted[0].length).setValues(extracted);

  return sourceSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
}

function update() {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(10000); // Wait (up to) 10s to acquire the lock

  var currentRow = getCurrentRow(); // currentRow is the row from which the script should run. i.e. if the last execution ended at row 2 (included), the value should be left to be 3. 1-indexed.
  var newCurrentRow = migrateRowsFrom(currentRow);
  updateCurrentRow(newCurrentRow);

  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

The function that you have to call is `update()`. It will fetch the row where the last execution left off, process as many rows as possible, and then update that value so the next execution knows where to start from.

Note that this will move the data from `Sheet1`, process it, and then paste it into `Sheet2`. Of course, you may change those values as you need. Also, be aware that you should not modify `Sheet1` values; since as they have already been processed they will not be processed again.